# How can I create STPCard stripe ios?

Tags: ios, swift, stripe-payments

I had the token of a customer saved card , how can I retrieve this card details as I want to view all customer saved cards using stripe ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you just can't retrieve card details by its token .. That token is used for payment once .. 
Now in order to store customer cards, you need to create customer account at stripe .. And then register your card with customer .. and you can retrieve all cards register with customer by customer id ..

Check this to create customer .. https://stripe.com/docs/api#customers

Check this to create card with customer .. https://stripe.com/docs/api#create_card

That's the whole procedure .. I have recently implemented that ..

Comment: So , in backend we should create customer account, and when customer add new card , in backend we should register this card to the customer and return the customer with his saved cards to iOS. true ?

Comment: Yup you need to save customer id, you will get one when you create customer on stripe, you will save that in your database or wherever you want to save it.   You can create charge, and can add and remove card using that..